# Parameterized paths in Mockoon

Tags: unit-testing, mockoon

I am new to Mockoon. I am creating a POC for using Mockoon as a replacement for some of our mocks in our test suite. Everything works well for both POST and GET requests. However, one issue I'm having: there is one endpoint that uses a parameterized path, something like this:

```
/access/<parameter>/endpointName
```

I need to set up Mockoon to be able to handle an endpoint that uses a parameter like this. Does anyone know how to do this, or, is it even possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockoon uses Express.js behind the scene. So, all of its [syntaxes](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) are supported.

To add a parameter to your endpoint you need to use the colon symbol: `/access/:param/endpointName`.
You will then be able to access the parameter inside the [rules](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/route-responses/dynamic-rules/#rules-logical-operator) or in your body using [templating helpers](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/templating/mockoon-request-helpers/#urlparam).